Why does using `/.` inside `Solve` change the result depending on the order of usage? Is this due to non-smoothness or an error?
For minimal example consider quadratic equation, with coefficients depending on parameter $po$. I have solution ys and I want to study how it changes with the change of parameter dp. The first and third variants are different compared to second one:

ClearAll;

as = {A > 2, po > 0, ys >= 0, y >= 0, p > 0, p >= (A - 1)/A};

ysSolve[p_, po_, y_] := Module[{yss},
   yss = 
    ys /. First[
      Solve[p  (y + (1/po)  (A - 1)  ys) == po A^2 ys^2, ys]];
   {yss}];

FullSimplify[
 Series[ysSolve[p, po, y][[1]] /. {po -> p + dp}, {dp, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> as], Assumptions -> as]


FullSimplify[
 Series[(ysSolve[p, po, y][[1]] /. {po -> p + dp}) - 
   ysSolve[p, p, y][[1]] , {dp, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> as], 
 Assumptions -> as]

FullSimplify[
 Series[(ysSolve[p, p + dp, y][[1]] ) - ysSolve[p, p, y][[1]] , {dp, 
   0, 1}, Assumptions -> as], Assumptions -> as]

Is this due to non smooth dependence of roots on coefficients for polynomials, or is there an error in my approach? If so, which one is correct?

Obviously there are two roots. Perhaps not as obvious is that there is no "natural" ordering of symbolic roots that depend on parameters. By "natural," I mean an ordering that corresponds to the numerical values when numbers are substituted for the parameters. Two solution sets produced by Solve[] might be equivalent, but the roots may be in a different order when values are substituted for the parameters, even when the values would result in equivalent equations.
For instance:
SeedRandom[0];
{ys /. Solve[p (y + (1/po) (a - 1) ys) == po a^2 ys^2, ys] /. po -> p + dp,
 ys /. Solve[p (y + (1/po) (a - 1) ys) == po a^2 ys^2 /. po -> p + dp, ys]}
% /. Thread[{a, p, dp, y} -> {2, 1, 0, 0} + RandomReal[1, {4}]]
(*
< long symbolic roots omitted >
{{-0.205163, 0.276679},
 {0.276679, -0.205163}}  <-- reversed order
*)

If we use the assumptions in Solve[], it turns out there is a unique real solution, so order does not matter. What's more, the symbolic expressions for the roots in each case turn out to be identical. The first result res1 seems a red herring as it calculates a different quantity than res2 and res3. I could not figure out why it is included. Maybe something was omitted in its code. It's commented out in the code below.
(*ClearAll;*)

as = {a > 2, po > 0, ys >= 0, y >= 0, p > 0, 
   p >= (a - 1)/a, -1/4096 < dp < 1/4096};

ysSolve[p_, po_, y_] := 
  Module[{yss}, 
   yss = ys /. 
     First[Solve[p (y + (1/po) (a - 1) ys) == po a^2 ys^2, ys, 
       Assumptions -> as]]; (* <-- NEW *)
   {yss}];

(* res1 = FullSimplify[
  Series[ysSolve[p, po, y][[1]] /. {po -> p + dp}, {dp, 0, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> as], Assumptions -> as] *)

res2 = FullSimplify[
  Series[(ysSolve[p, po, y][[1]] /. {po -> p + dp}) - 
    ysSolve[p, p, y][[1]], {dp, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> as], 
  Assumptions -> as]

res3 = FullSimplify[
  Series[(ysSolve[p, p + dp, y][[1]]) - ysSolve[p, p, y][[1]], {dp, 0,
     1}, Assumptions -> as], Assumptions -> as]
(* < long symbolic solutions omitted >

res2 === res3
(*  True  *)

The line ClearAll; does nothing. And I hate it when people include ClearAll["Global`*"] in code on the site, since it clears things I don't want cleared. Also, I change A to a, as usual. I added res1, res2, and res3 to make discussing the OP's code easier.

One can sort the solutions by the numerical values at a point: orderProxy[sol_] := Block[{a, p, po, dp, y},    {a, p, dp, y} = {2.1, 1.1, 0.00001, 0.1};    po = p + dp;    ys /. sol]; SortBy[Solve[p (y + (1/po) (a - 1) ys) == po a^2 ys^2, ys], orderProxy]

Also, how do I actually clean all? Quit and restart kernel?

@Moonwalker ClearAll["Global`*"] will clear all the definitions you have made in the global context, which normally is everything you've defined. I usually Quit[], which might take a few seconds longer. My gripe about ClearAll["Global`*"] is that it clears anything I've defined that I might still want to use. You may find it helpful or even necessary to clear your prior defs in your own session, and I have no problem with that. But if users think they're being helpfuI by including it in their posts here, I wish to point out that they are not. I can handle things in a different way.

Re: "But if users think they're being helpfuI by including it in their posts here, I wish to point out that they are not. I can handle things in a different way." However, you are not typically the target audience for an answer -- you don't need help. Answers are mostly intended to assist novices (not even necessarily the OP). I generally include Clear["Global``*"] to assist novices that might not yet know to clear out old definitions.

@BobHanlon If I am not the target audience, then there is no point in my trying help.

Some background: When I first got Mma, I read through Wolfram's Mathematica and discovered Clear["Global`*"]. Unsure about the difference between Clear and ClearAll, I thought Remove["Global`*"] would be even better. It would get rid of definitions that were messing up my work. I quickly realized it was a bit like dropping a nuclear bomb. Not only did it destroyed the enemy definitions, it destroyed everything else. Including the data it had taken half an hour to computed that I was trying to figure out the next step. Clearing everything was not helpful to this novice.

I said that you are not the target audience of an answer. That in no way implies that your help isn’t needed or appreciated by me or the community.

@BobHanlon My remark to which you were responding was about questions. I don't feel I need to check your work, since I trust you to do a good job. Anyway as my last comment implies, Clear["Global`*"] is not necessarily that helpful in answers, especially for users who do not understand what it does. It would be better to clear just the variables that need clearing.
